# Using Sequel Pro: How do I update a column that contains a query?

Tags: sql, sql-update

So basically I have a column called 'query' which contains a query.  I need to update that query but don't know how.

I tried a simple

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET QUERY = 'New Query'
WHERE ID = 1
```

but it's getting thrown out because of the pre-existing ' ' that I have in the query.

Way out of my league on this one. Trying to learn on the fly for a position that's going to open up.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Your statement is fine (assuming you don't really have a table named `TABLE`)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape the ' in the query, possibly by doubling them up or using an escape char before them:

```
UPDATE t
SET query = 'DELETE FROM x WHERE y = ''z'' '
WHERE ID = 1


UPDATE t
SET query = 'DELETE FROM x WHERE y = \'z\' ' ESCAPE '\'
WHERE ID = 1
```

You can also make life easier/neater with REPLACE, like:

```
UPDATE t
SET query = REPLACE('DELETE FROM x WHERE y = "z" AND a = "b" AND c = "d" ', '"', CHAR(39))
```

This way you can use some char all through that doesn't occur naturally in the query, and replace it with `'` at the end

I can't say which variant works for your DB because you didn't say what your DB was..
WHERE ID = 1